# FullCategoryCollection works only on first chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So, this code does what I want, to reset the categories in a graph, on the first. It runs through all charts, I get the index right, use the name of the graph, at this point I'm not sure what to try anymore. Any light to shed on my poor mortal coil?

```
Public countIndex As Integer
Sub Botão1_Clique()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim countChart As Long
    Dim check As Variant
    Dim wkdad As Worksheet
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wkdad = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
    i = 25
    y = 1
    countIndex = 0
    check = wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
    Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1.Clear
    
    Do While check <> ""
        With Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1
            .AddItem wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
        End With
        wkdad.ChartObjects("Gráfico " & y).Activate
        z = ActiveChart.Parent.Index
        With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(z)
          countChart = .FullCategoryCollection.Count
          For x = 1 To countChart
            .FullCategoryCollection(x).IsFiltered = False
          Next
        End With
        i = i + 1
        y = y + 1
        countIndex = countIndex + 1
        check = wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
    Loop

    
    Cad_Vendas.Show
    Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: First step, remove `On Error Resume Next` and see what line(s) throw error(s).

Comment: Right, second time it runs the loop it gives out error 1004, invalid parameter.

Comment: Which line throws that error? Also it's probably better to use a variable rather than using `.Activate` and `ActiveChart`.

Comment: With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(z) (the second time around it runs)

Comment: About the .Activate and ActiveChart, it does work at selecting the charts, so it is not that at least.

Comment: `z = ActiveChart.Parent.Index` and `.ChartGroups(z)` seems off. Likely your chart does not have multiple `ChartGroup`s.

Comment: I just tried just that. Was Coming here to post the solution. I took off the z variable, and put 1 as the fixed index. Worked like a charm. (except the last chart, that is a dynamic chart instead of the normal ones I use for most of the dashboard I'm building).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public countIndex As Integer
Sub Botão1_Clique()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim countChart As Long
Dim check As Variant
Dim wkdad As Worksheet
Dim y As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Set wkdad = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
i = 25
y = 1
countIndex = 0
check = wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1.Clear

Do While check <> ""
    With Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1
        .AddItem wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
    End With
    wkdad.ChartObjects("Gráfico " & y).Activate
    With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1)
      countChart = .FullCategoryCollection.Count
      For x = 1 To countChart
        .FullCategoryCollection(x).IsFiltered = False
      Next
    End With
    i = i + 1
    y = y + 1
    countIndex = countIndex + 1
    check = wkdad.Cells(i, 7)
Loop


Cad_Vendas.Show
Cad_Vendas.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

This code works. The problem was that that the `ChartGroups(z)` was suposed to be always (1), so the variable z was making it only work with the first chart, as every chart had its own ChartGroups index starting at 1.